# How stay loged even if i reload the page

Tags: angular, flask

---

before all you need to know that im learning about backend-frontend and all your tips are welcome, i want to learn the best way possible.

---

im using Flask and Angular, in my web app i do a login, but when i reload the page i dont stay loged, how can i do to stay loged even if i reload the page

this is my backend:

```
@app.route('/user/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    r_first_name=request.get_json()['first_name']
    r_last_name=request.get_json()['last_name']
    r_email=request.get_json()['email']
    r_comp=request.get_json()['password']
    r_password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.get_json()['password']).decode('utf-8')
    result=""
    
    if user_database_service.if_email_domain(r_email) == False:
        result="Invalid Email"
        print(result)
        return jsonify({'result': result})

    if user_database_service.if_user_exists(r_email):
        result="user already exists"
        print(result)
        return jsonify({'result': result})

    if user_database_service.if_user_number(r_first_name, r_last_name) == False:
        result="The Names are invalid"
        print(result)
        return jsonify({'result': result})

    if len(r_comp) < 5:
        result="Password Length"
        print(result)
        return jsonify({'result': result})
    r_comp = ""
     
    new_user=LocalUser(first_name=r_first_name, last_name=r_last_name, email=r_email, password=r_password, created=datetime.utcnow())
    added=user_database_service.add_user(new_user)
    if added is True:
        result="user successfully added"
        print(result)
    else:
        result="unable to add"
        print(result)
    return jsonify({'result': result})


@app.route('/user/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    email=request.get_json()['email']
    password=request.get_json()['password']
    result=""

    response_user=user_database_service.get_user(email)

    if response_user:
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(response_user.password, password):
            access_token=create_access_token(
                identity=
                {
                    'first_name': response_user.first_name,
                    'last_name': response_user.last_name,
                    'email': response_user.email
                }
            )
            result=jsonify({'token': access_token})
        else:
            result=jsonify({'error': 'Invalid username or password'})
    return result
```

and this is my authentication_service in angular:

```
export interface UserDetails
{
  _id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  password: string
  exp: number
  iat: number
}

interface TokenResponse
{
  token: string
}

export interface TokenPayload
{
  id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  password: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  private token!: string;

  private saveToken(token: string): void
  {
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', token)
    this.token=token
  }

  private getToken(): string
  {
    
    if(!this.token)
    {
      this.token==localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
    }
   
    return this.token
  }

  public getUserDetails(): UserDetails
  {
    const token=this.getToken()
    
    let payload
    var x
    if(token)
    {
      payload=token.split('.')[1]
      payload=window.atob(payload)
      x = JSON.parse(payload)
      
      return JSON.parse(payload)

      
    }
    else
    {
        return null as any
        
    }
  }

  public getUserInfo(busqueda:string): UserDetails
  {

    const token=this.getToken()
    
    let payload
    var x
    if(token)
    {
      payload=token.split('.')[1]
      payload=window.atob(payload)
      x = JSON.parse(payload)
     x['sub'][busqueda]
      return x['sub'][busqueda]
    }
    else
    {
        return null as any
        
    }
  }
  

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean
  {
    const user=this.getUserDetails()
    
    if(user)
    {
      
      return user.exp > Date.now()/1000
    }
    else
    {
      return false
    }
  }

  public register(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>
  {
    const base=this.http.post<TokenResponse>(`http://localhost:3000/user/register`, user)
    const request=base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token)
        {
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        console.log(data)

        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        console.log("Este es x: " + x)
        if ( x == '{"result":"Password Length"}')
        {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error en el registro',
            text: "La contraseña debe ser mayor a 5 caracteres",
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'
        })
      }

        if ( x == '{"result":"Invalid Email"}')
        {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error en el registro',
            text: "El Email ingresado es invalido",
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'
        })
        
      }

      if ( x == '{"result":"user already exists"}')
        {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error en el registro',
            text: "El Email ingresado ya existe",
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'
        })
        
      }

      if ( x == '{"result":"The Names are invalid"}')
      {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Error en el Registro',
          text: "Los nombres no deben contener numeros",
          icon: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'
      })
      
    }

      if ( x == '{"result":"user successfully added"}')
        {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'El registro es valido',
            text: "El Email ingresado es invalido",
            icon: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'
        }).then((result)=> {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')
        }
        })
        
      }
      
    
      console.log(data)
        return data
        
      })
    )
    
    return request
  }

/*
  public register(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>
  {
    console.log(this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/user/register`, user))
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/user/register`, user)
  }
  */
  public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>
  {
    const base=this.http.post<TokenResponse>(`http://localhost:3000/user/login`, user)
    const request=base.pipe(
    map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token)
        {
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        console.log(data)
        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        console.log("Este es x: " + x)
        if ( x == '{"error":"Invalid username or password"}')
        {
          console.log("ENTRO MI LOCO")
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Login Invalido',
            text: "Haz ingresado la contraseña incorrecta",
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'})
        }
        

        return data
      })
    )
    console.log("Request: " + request)
    return request
    
  }

  public logout(): void
  {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Se ha cerrado la sesion',
      text: "Se ha cerrado de la sesion actual",
      icon: 'error',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK!'
     
  })
    this.token=''
    
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to stay login status,you can use cookie, this is normal method.
or send token in request data every time.
when you request login url,told browser send cookie to you every time.

```
session = "user token"
res = make_response()
    res.set_cookie('session', session)
return res
```

use this method to get session in cookie:

```
session = request.cookies.get('session')
```

a simple cookie check func:

```
@app.before_request
    def before_request():
        session = request.cookies.get('session')
        if not session :
            return jsonify({'result': "not login"})
        return None
```

Comment: where should i add this? i dont really dont understand how should i add this in my code, if you can help me i would appreciate it!

Comment: @andres-cobar use `before request` to check cookie, you can see flask document in [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/)